# CORS Issues with Google Vision API Calls

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am making a call to Google's Vision API using Ajax. I have completed billing and received an API key. However once implemented, I am getting errors like this:

"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."

I have tried using solutions I found online like setting the request header to "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" and using a Chrome Extension. If anybody can help that would be excellent.

```
var request = {     
    "requests": [{
              "image": {
                "content": url,
              },
              "features": [{
                  "type": "WEB_DETECTION",
                  "maxResults": 1
               }]
            }]
     }

$.ajax({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' + key,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: JSON.stringify(request),
     processData: false,
     beforeSend: function(req) {
         req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
         console.log(req);
     },
     success: function(data){
         console.log("Data: " + data);
         var webData = data.responses[0].webAnnotations[0];
         console.log("Web Data: " + webData);
     },
     error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log('error: ' + errorThrown);
     }
});
```

Comment: why are you setting a **response** header in a **request**? `setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` get rid of it. Also, does the API in question require `JSON` content-type? because those two things will trigger a pre-flight

Comment: Looking at the request from the example. a) the content-type for the request is `text/plain`, but the request parameter is a JSON string. - so try `contentType: 'text/plain,` and remove that response header from the request

Comment: I removed the response header and changed the contentType so there is no longer a pre-flight, but I get this error: 

"The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Are you making the request from a local file `file:///` ?

Comment: Yes, but the file is converted to Base64 and stored in the variable "url"

Comment: I don't mean where does the (image?) file come from ... I mean .. the web page itself ... is it `file:///`, and are you perhaps running Chrume?

Comment: Yes it is a file:/// and I am running Chrome

Comment: well, that's the problem ... because Chrome wont allow it without a command line flag (which is extremely dangerous) perhaps no browser will allow it ... it's been literally decades since I've developed without a web server

Comment: How would you suggest I solve this problem?

Comment: use a web server ... or, now that you've fixed the preflight, investigate the "Chrome Extension" you tried

Comment: I tried this and I get this error

The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'null, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Oh ... so the chrome extension is adding `*` to the existing `null` ... that's a pretty crap extension then!! There is some command line option that may help, but I have no clue where to search for chrome command line options ... --disable-web-security perhaps (though, this is extremely unwise and dangerous, highly recommend you use a web server instead)

Comment: Just resolved everything and it seems to be working smoothly. Thank you!

Comment: @SanketDange can you post an answer explaining how you solved it?

Comment: I followed @JaromandaX 's advice up until the very end. I then downloaded this extension to enable CORS:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en

Comment: @VictorGGl - I would not recommend that extension ... it doesn't "enable CORS" - it bypasses CORS, it's useless for any true web developers, because you can't tell people they must use chrome (I mean, why would anyone subject people to that piece of rubbish) and must install some dodgy extension!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to summarise the discussion in the comments here:

When making cross domain API calls if the website file is opened using the `file://` protocol, the API calls are usually rejected by the browser. To circumvent this, try running a local server and accessing it from there.

I usually use the npm package `http-server`

```
npm i -g http-server
cd /path/to/folder/with/static/files
http-server
```

Your website will be accessible at http://localhost:8080

EDIT: You will need [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed to use npm

If you don't have NodeJS, you could also install Apache or Nginx or XAMPP to do the same thing.

There is also a handy service called [Surge.sh](http://surge.sh) which allows you to easily deploy a website to a custom subdomain on surge.sh.

Comment: `I usually use the npm package` - perhaps you should mention this requires `node.js` :p