# call google vision api from vue client

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api, google-vision

I'm following the [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request) to use the Vision API but unfortunately I continue getting the following `CORS` error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=MY_KEY_HERE' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What I'm doing is this in a **Vue** template:

```
    const googleRequestData = {
      requests: [
        {
          image: {
            content: base64Image
          },
          features: [
            {
              type: 'LABEL_DETECTION',
              maxResults: 10
            },
            {
              type: 'SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    const gv = await this.$axios.$post(
      `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=${
        process.env.googleApplicationCredentials
      }`,
      googleRequestData
    )
    console.log('google vision', gv)
```

It looks pretty simple but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something that as usual it is not well documented and I can not go ahead...

I hope you can help! Thanks

Comment: Can you try it with wrong credentials to see if it responses with 403 or something else rather than cors?

Comment: Same error using a wrong key.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can take a [look at Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors) about allowing your domain so you can make Cross Origin Requests to you Vision Api
2. Secondly you can make your requests from a server(eg node.js) and serve your Vue.js app with that server, and in that server you can make requests to Vision API so that you can use that api with Vue.js so it will not blocked by CORS. [You can take a look at](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/05/07/vue-js-backends-express-laravel-firebase-wordpress-django-rails/) what backend you can use with Vue.js

Comment: I'm not using a google cloud server nor any other servers. This is a very simple client side application that consume a couple of endpoints, one of these is the Google Vision. There is no chance to create a node server on top of it. It should work directly from the front-end.

Comment: Look at this issue right here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49912946 It also recommends using http server to make the request

Comment: I will try asking if I can implement a server and in case I will try this solution. Thanks

Comment: Okey, also you can take a look at my sample project with Vue and Node as well https://github.com/onuriltan/NoteManager